# How diable extension method for one class

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have class

`View`

Also i have class Button inheritance View

`Button:View`

I add extension method `Click` for `View`, but a don`t want see this method for button.

Can i do this?

Comment: This does of course mean you OO model is wrong, apparently a Button IS-not-A View

Comment: `((View) button).ExtensionMethod()` would still be legal anyway, so make sure what it is you want -- not "seeing" the method is not the same as not being able to call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of to this is to create a method (whether extension or instance) with the same signature except it is on `Button` rather than on `View` so that it takes priority, and then mark it as `[Obsolete]` so that you get warned or blocked from actually using it.

You would still be able to call your `Click()` on a `Button` that was accessed via a `View` reference though.